# '-to' option for trimming a video doesn't work unless cmd is run from the folder where ffmpeg is located

Tags: windows, command-line, video, ffmpeg

I'm using'-to' option for trimming a video and ffmpeg says 'to' option not recongnized if ffmpeg.exe is run from a folder other than where ffmpeg.exe is located through cmd.exe. The location of ffmpeg.exe is in windows system path.

Comment: What version of `ffmpeg.exe` is being reported when you are running it from another directory?

Comment: You should show your actual commands and the complete console outputs (please copy and paste instead of making screenshots; not sure why that is so common for Windows users).

Comment: Hi, I was able to figure out the issue. I tried to provide ffmpeg version and console log for both cases where it is working and failing. Looking at the log i was able to figure out that version of ffmpeg printed in the console log is different in both cases. Version details for your reference.  New version N-75185-gf58e011 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 built with gcc 4.9.3 (GCC)...Old version N-34549-g13b7781,Copyright (c) 2000-2011 Nov  6 2011 with gcc 4.6.1....The old version was in path which doesn't support '-to'. Removing old version from path solved my problem. Thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: That's usually the case for problems with not recognised commands :) You can write that as an answer and accept that, since it fixed your problem, which would help others in a similar predicament.

Answer (score 2):

This could happen if an old version of `ffmpeg` was used with latest supported options. In my case I had 2 different versions of `ffmpeg` in Windows system path. Below are the 2 version I had on my machine:

- New version `N-75185-gf58e011 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 built with gcc 4.9.3 (GCC)` which supports `-to` option.
- Old version `N-34549-g13b7781 Copyright (c) 2000-2011 Nov 6 2011 with gcc 4.6.1` which doesn't support `-to`.

Using Windows task manager I was able to figure out that an old version of `ffmpeg` was being used when the video trim failed with `-to` option. Removing the old version from system path solved my issue.